# Visual Studio does not underline error (cend is not a member of...)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I downloaded these 2 codes from GitHub because I want to edit them without having to recompile Point Cloud Library. I have edited the relevant includes so that the new hpp files links to the new h file.

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/segmentation/include/pcl/segmentation/supervoxel_clustering.h
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/segmentation/include/pcl/segmentation/impl/supervoxel_clustering.hpp

However, I get an error as shown below. It says cend is not a member of a certain class. My question is, why doesn't visual studio underline the errors I get ?

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio's Intellisense, as of VS 2015, doesn't use the compiler proper for its checking. It uses its own engine. The two do not always agree, and Intellisense often uses some time to build up results.

Comment: Hi thanks. So what are you suggesting ? That I have to wait for Intellisense to build up results ? Then it will show the errors ?

Comment: For this case I would simply accept the imperfection. In some cases Intellisense can foul up its state and then it's possible to delete some files to help it get back on track. At the cost that it then has to rescan everything in the solution.

Comment: Except you use a tool like ReSharper for C++ or CLion, it would be quite difficult to get instant error reports.